When running a Support Vector Machine, how do I formulate the linear transformation that flips the decision hyperplane in the non-augmented dimension?
We know that when running a support vector machine, we actually use the "kernel trick" to compute the decision hyperplane (boundary) as if we do so in the kernel-augmented dimension, but not actually in the kernel-augmented dimension. My question is, if there is some transformation in the kernel-augmented dimension, such as a linear transformation that flips the decision hyperplane, how can this transformation be mathematically formulated without an explicit higher dimensional mapping, similar to the way the kernel trick works?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
